# proving property ( and Brouwer's fixed point theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let be $ K:= \overline{K_1(0)} $ a closed unit disk in $ \mathbb{R^2} $.

I want to show that:

(i) There does not exist a continuous function $ f: K \rightarrow \partial K$, so that $f(x)=x ,\forall x \in \partial K $

(ii) Brouwer's fixed point theorem:
Any continuous function $f: K \rightarrow K$ has a fixed point
(by using (i) )

__

for (i)
I need to to set a homotopy $H(t,s):= f(s \cos t, s \sin t )$ and $\omega = (x^2+y^2)^{-1} (-y dx+xdy))$ to prove contradiction. Do you have any idea for this?

for (ii)
I have setted up a proof

Comment: This is the standard approach to proving the BFPT, and can be found in nearly any topology book or webpage about the theorem.

Comment: $K$ is the closed unit disk. The closed unit circle is $S^1 = \partial K$. (i) is wrong, (ii) is only a rudiment of a statement.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: @Randall unfortunatly, I just found different approaches to the proof

Comment: Your approach by no-retracts is one of the approaches listed here:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: I edited you question because in the present form it does not make sense.

Comment: thanks ! I still don't know how to use the Homotopy to show that there does not exist such a function

Comment: Do you know what $\pi_1(\partial K)$ is ? Or maybe $H_1(\partial K; \mathbb{Z})$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The map $f$, if it exists, will retract $K$ to $\partial K$.

Recall the following little lemma (Lemma 55.1, Munkres).

**Lemma:** If A is a retract of X, then the homomorphism of fundamental groups induced by inclusion $i:A\to X$ is injective.

Now it is clear what one should do. Observe that fundamental group of $\partial K$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, while that of $K$ is trivial. There is no way to give an injective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to trivial group. Which proves that such a map $f$ is not possible.

For the second problem, assume that $f$ does not have a fixed point. This means for every $x$ and $f(x)$ are two distinct points. Great! If you have two distinct points in the disk, you can draw a line through them and hit the boundary. That’s exactly what you do, start from $f(x)$ and go to the boundary passing through $x$. Check that this gives you a continuous function from $K$ to its boundary which fixes the boundary. But, we just proved such a map is not possible.